# WordPress and www subdomain

Tags: wordpress, apache, dns, subdomain

I have setup WordPress for my domain `xyz.test.`

In my domain configuration I have set the A entry for the `www` subdomain to the same A entry as for the primary domain (`xyz.test`).

However, when entering `www.xyz.test` in the browser, it does not go to my WordPress server, but only returns Apache`s "No content message".

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache allows name based virtual hosts. This means you can host multiple FQDNs on the same IP address. You need to add a name based virtual host for `www.xyz.test` that points to the same directory. Or you could add a server alias in the `xyz.test` virtualhost configuration:

```
ServerName xyz.test
ServerAlias www.xyz.test
```

Comment: I have added the ServerAlias to the WordPress virtualhost ("wordpress") configuration file right after the server name, but it did not resolve the issue. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is name based virtual hosting on?

Comment: I got it to work by using ServerAlias *.xyz.test. How can I find out about "name based virtual hosting"? I haven`t changed any default values except ServerName and ServerAlias.